# Multipage FormFunction "Required" FormObject broken with "FileName" interpreter

Tags: bugs, gui-construction, wolfram-cloud, form-building

Multipage `FormFunction` does not validate `FormObject`s with "FileName" interpreter if the field is left blank.

Minimal example

```
FormFunction[
 {
  {"Filename" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "FileName", "Required" -> True|>}
  ,
  {"Stuff" -> "String"}
  },
 Identity
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Here you should need to enter a valid filename to proceed. However, if you simply select the "Next" button without entering a value it proceeds to the next page.

This is not the case for other types. For example a `"Number"` interpreter will not allow you to proceed, as expected.

```
FormFunction[
 {
  {"Number" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "Number", "Required" -> True|>}
  ,
  {"Stuff" -> "String"}
  },
 Identity
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Any ideas what is going on here and how to get the `"FileName"` interpreter to cooperate?

---

[CASE:4024369]